# Fiona: name 'rec' is not defined

Tags: python, geospatial, fiona

I'm learning Python for GIS operations and I would like to duplicate a shapefile with Fiona.

I'm trying to reproduct the [official example](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#creating-files-of-the-same-structure).

```
import fiona

input_folder = '../test-input/'
input_data_name = 'input.shp'
input_data = input_folder+input_data_name

output_folder = '../test-output/'
output_data_name = 'output.shp'
output_data = output_folder+output_data_name


with fiona.open(input_data, 'r') as src:
    source_driver = src.driver
    source_crs = src.crs
    source_schema = src.schema

with fiona.open(
        output_data,
        'w',
        driver=source_driver,
        crs=source_crs,
        schema=source_schema
) as dup:
    dup.write(rec)
    dup.close()
```

When I use this code I see this error:

> NameError: name 'rec' is not defined

It is the same code from the example except for file name and data folder.

Comment: where is `rec` defined at? (in the line `dup.write(rec)`)

Comment: `dup.write(rec)` : rec is never defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the beginning of the documentation examples:

```py
with fiona.open('docs/data/test_uk.shp') as c:
    rec = next(c)
```

Comment: It's run but I see this warning: `FionaDeprecationWarning: Collection.__next__() is buggy and will be removed in Fiona 2.0. Switch to `next(iter(collection))`.
  rec = next(src)`

Comment: Then, try as the warning tells you: `rec = next(iter(c))`